# Using an acronym from acro inside math mode

Tags: math-mode, acro

```
\DeclareAcronym{os}{
short  = \text{OS},
long = observed space,
short-format = \scshape
}
```

I'd like to use the short form in math mode, such as

`$f : \acs{os} \to R$`

but I get an error complaining that \scshape cannot be used in math mode.

Is there a workaround for this? I can always break up the math around the acronym, but that messes up the spacing and seems less elegant a solution.

Comment: I haven't tried it (because you haven't provided a minimum working example), but maybe `$f : \textrm{\acs{os}} \to R$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For uppercase letters `\scshape` usually looks the same as `\upshape` which means that for your acronym

```
\DeclareAcronym{os}{
  short  = \text{OS},
  long = observed space,
  short-format = \scshape
}
```

you can just leave the `short-format = \scshape` away.

For text in math-mode you can use `amsmath`'s `\text` (which you are using already in the definition of your acronym…)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro,amsmath}

\DeclareAcronym{os}{
  short = os ,
  long = observed space ,
  short-format = \scshape
}

\begin{document}

$f : \textrm{\acs{os}} \to R$ \par
$f : \text{\acs{os}} \to R$

\end{document}
```

[image]